# How can I use .Net Reflector to look into an app?

Tags: c#

I want to use .Net Reflector to reverse engineering a windows application. All I have is the setup.exe and an .application file under the app.publish folder. When use .Net reflector, it doesn't work with setup.exe. Am I able to see the codes or it is not possible?  Any other options?  Thank you for replying.

Comment: You can look only to those exe which are made in .net and c# or VB... and which are not encripted...

Answer (score 4):

The `setup.exe` is not a .NET application. You need to install the application and then open the installed `.exe` with reflector.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from jetbrains.

Comment: Does not help with the "non-.NET" setup.exe...